# Unwanted space between UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I've got a UICollectionView, and have a custom UICollectionTableViewCell with a UIImageViewInside.

I've got the spacings as followed:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // TODO: Select Item
}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // TODO: Deselect item
}




#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewFlowLayout
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0f;
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0f;
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    return flowLayout;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat widthOfTheScreen =self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGSize retval = CGSizeMake(widthOfTheScreen , widthOfTheScreen *1.5);
    return retval;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Now, when I run it, it works perfectly for my purpose. It shows the image in the centre of the view (I've got my collectionview under a label), and it shows it almost exactly how I wanted it (don't worry about the shortage of bottom space bit).

The image below shows the first item (without scrolling):

[image]

However, when I scroll right, I start to get slight gaps. Also, this gap gets bigger with every scroll (I have the background red so you can see).

This is the first scroll:

[image]

This is the second scroll:

[image]

And this is the third scroll:

[image]

And so on goes the pattern. I've got a feeling that it's something to do with the insets, but not sure how to remove it.

OR is it something to do with some outset? I've never heard of such, but that could also be the problem

Thanks a lot in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, your UI feels and looks pretty strange.  I certainly hope the imageview is not nested inside another scrollview inside the collection view.  If you care to put the project up we can run it to see what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No I used the collectionview inside a view controller. no scrollview used. I'll post the github rep address as soon as I get home.